# Difficulties on getting ID from Array[]

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a project and using codeigniter i want to get the id from the array im new in codeigniter  but idont know hot to get the id  here is the result

i'm getting the id from the session

CONTROLLER

```
public function index()
    {   
              $id = $this->session->userdata('account');// this will Display the array 
/******
     Array
    (
        [ID] => 4
        [account_name] => HANDSOME
        [nickname] => PROGRAM
        [email] => JAMPONG@ya.com
        [type] => 1
    )

/************************       

$update=$this->load->model('profile_m');

        $this->add_data('title','RESERVED')
             ->add_data('text', "THIS IS A DYNAMIC TEXT, or some other data");

        $data['profile_id'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->add_data('updated',$data['profile_id']); 
        $this->display_view('profile/profile_v');
    }
```

i want to get the accout ID

Comment: Please include the code you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: http://php.net/language.types.array#example-88

Comment: where did the array came from? is it from in model or post value? include something relevant because if you're trying to access simple array , codeigniter has nothing to do with it

Comment: already working tnx  to all who help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$account = Array(
    'ID' => 4,
    'account_name' => 'HANDSOME'.
    'nickname' => 'PROGRAM',
    'email' => 'JAMPONG@ya.com',
    'type' => 1);
$account_id =  $account['ID'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$id = $this->session->userdata('account');` first `$id` is not a good name for holding an array value like in your setup,

so something like this will be good:

```
$account = $this->session->userdata('account');
```

then to access the id:

```
$account['ID'];
```